# How to work with two Stripe account in 'one' app

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I am a newbie in iOS and also newbie in Stripe pay with iOS I want to pay Two Stripe account in iOS like as first I want to pay in One and after successfully pay in one account as soon as possible I want to pay in to second account for that I write a code like as:

```
"Transaction Start"


-(void)startTransaction
{
 if ([self validateCustomerInfo])
 {
    [Stripe setDefaultPublishableKey:STRIPE_TEST_PUBLIC_KEY1];
    STPCardParams *card = [[STPCardParams alloc] init];
    card.number = txtCardNumber.text;
    card.expMonth =[btnMonth.titleLabel.text integerValue];
    card.expYear = [btnYear.titleLabel.text integerValue];
    card.cvc = txtCvv.text;
    [[STPAPIClient sharedClient] createTokenWithCard:card
                                          completion:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error) {
                                              if (error) {
                                                  [GlobalClass StopSpinner:self.view];
                                                  [AppDelegate ShowAlert:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[error localizedDescription]]];
                                              } else {
                                                  [self postStripeToken:token];
                                              }
                                          }];
}
}

#Generated First Token.


-(void)postStripeToken:(STPToken*)token
{
   [GlobalClass ActivateSpinner:self.view StringMSG:@"Please wait"];
   NSDictionary *parameter=@{@"secretkey":STRIPE_SECRET_KEY1,@"stripeToken":token.tokenId,@"amount":@"2",@"currency":@"usd",@"description":@"iOS Transaction"};
   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
   manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes =          [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
   [manager POST:@"http://s570166064.onlinehome.us/seadealersWS/payment/payment.php" parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"Responce Object %@",responseObject);
     if ([[responseObject valueForKey:@"status"]isEqualToString:@
         "Success"])
     {
     # Here i want to Pay in second account #

         [Stripe setDefaultPublishableKey:STRIPE_TEST_PUBLIC_KEY2];
         STPCardParams *card = [[STPCardParams alloc] init];
         card.number = txtCardNumber.text;
         card.expMonth =[btnMonth.titleLabel.text integerValue];
         card.expYear = [btnYear.titleLabel.text integerValue];
         card.cvc = txtCvv.text;
         [[STPAPIClient sharedClient] createTokenWithCard:card
                                               completion:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error) {
                                                   if (error) {
                                                       [GlobalClass StopSpinner:self.view];
                                                       [AppDelegate ShowAlert:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[error localizedDescription]]];
                                                   } else {
                                                       [GlobalClass StopSpinner:self.view];
                                        [GlobalClass ActivateSpinner:self.view StringMSG:@"Please wait"];

                                                       [self postStripeTokenTwo:token];
                                                   }
                                               }];
     }
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     [GlobalClass StopSpinner:self.view];
     [AppDelegate ShowAlert:@"Please try again"];
     NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
 }];
 }
 -(void)postStripeTokenTwo:(STPToken*)token
 {
NSDictionary *parameter=@{@"secretkey":STRIPE_SECRET_KEY2,@"stripeToken":token.tokenId,@"amount":@"0.5",@"currency":@"usd",@"description":@"iOS Transaction"};
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
[manager POST:@"http://s570166064.onlinehome.us/seadealersWS/payment/payment.php" parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"Responce Object %@",responseObject);
     if ([[responseObject valueForKey:@"status"]isEqualToString:@
          "Success"])
     {
         [GlobalClass StopSpinner:self.view];
     }
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     [GlobalClass StopSpinner:self.view];
     [AppDelegate ShowAlert:@"Please try again"];
     NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
 }];
```

}

But for First account i get success response but for Second account it says that Your token is not valid i not want to set stripe connect.
Thank you, and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1):

A token can only be used once and is only valid in the account that created it. You would have to use two tokens (one created per account)

Also, you should not be shipping your Stripe secret API key in your app. Strings in application code can easily be discoverable and you do not want to leak your API key. The standard approach is to send the token to a server you control and from your server send the API call.

In addition, you may want to take a look at Stripe Connect, it may be a better approach to your issue then storing api keys of multiple accounts.

Comment: #Matthew here I create two different tiken for different account please check code once.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is exist in the older versions of Stripe SDK

In order to resolve this issue

1) upgrade the SDK to the latest version(13.2.0)

```
pod Stripe, '~>13.2.0'
pod install --repo-update
```

2) Instead of setting

```
STPPaymentConfiguration.shared().publishableKey = STRIPE_TEST_PUBLIC_KEY1
```

use

```
STPAPIClient.shared().publishableKey = STRIPE_TEST_PUBLIC_KEY1
```

3) Clean and run the project and it will work as expected.

[Please refer this link for more information](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/issues/880)